# Submitting Jquery wizard Form ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, session, struts2, wizard

I am using Jquery for UI and Struts2 in the Back End .I got a requirement such that i have to make a JQuery Wizard and have to submit the form to database ..

The problem is , am going to insert values into six table in the database , ie. Each page in the wizard represents one table in the database . And in overall there are 72 elements that belongs to these six table.

In the above scenario what would be the best decision in persisting the database :

1. Using JSP session

   **Doubt :** am wondering how to get this session object back to struts2 action class?
2. Storing each page in a list and send all the list at the time of form submission .

   **Doubt :** When we send a **Java List** of all elements in each page as a normal query string  , whether is it possible to retrieve it as a **List** . The code am using to retrieve query String is : 
   Am implementing `ServletRequestAware` interface in my **Action class** and

   ```
       public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
       this.request = httpServletRequest;
         }

       public final Map getParameters() {
       parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
       return parameters;
       }

       public String getParameterValue(String param) {
       Object paramObj = getParameters().get(param);
       if (paramObj == null)
           return null;
       return ((String[]) paramObj)[0];
       }
   ```
3. By creating a duplicate table in the database for each table . But i cant use as per the requirement .

Please suggest me if there is anyway to achieve this which should not affect the performance of the application . And also clear me the above doubts .

**For Critics :**
Currently am doing a background work on the JSP session in Struts2 and trying to incorporate with the examples i got.

Please Guide me what to do further ..

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: if you have a lot of data Jquery means you need to serialize all the data which seems a lot of work for me, session @jsp is what provided by the container so it will be available to Strtuts2 also, have a look at struts2 scope interceptor to see how to build a wizard type functionality.

Comment: Why would you bypass the default Struts 2 parameter handling and type conversion functionality? They are what would enable you to get an actual list object.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you for the suggestion , But can you please elaborate your explanation

Comment: @Esh Type conversion is what converts simple strings, the *only* thing HTTP can send, into lists. You're directly accessing the request, instead of using S2's default parameter and type conversion process.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hmmm . Let me try this out and let you know